# Reactotron is crashing with white blank screen while debugging

Tags: react-native, debugging, reactotron

Reactotron works normally after application launching on simulator but after few moments it turns suddenly to blank white screen ( nothing changed in env. setup or configurations)

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this? I’m having the same problem, on the previous commit without Reactotron everything is fine. As soon as I add and initialise reactotron i get a white screen that’s not responsive

Comment: Not solved till now, I have to close and reopen it